# switch to create number of symbols

Tags: c#

This code shows an icons from the Segoe MDL2 Assets font, depending on the number in a variable. However, I'm sure there is a more elegant way of doing this.

```
switch (numberOfPeople)
{
    case 0:
        return "";
    case 1:
        return "\xE77B";
    case 2:
        return "\xE77B \xE77B";
    case 3:
        return "\xE77B \xE77B \xE77B";
    case 4:
        return "\xE77B \xE77B \xE77B \xE77B";
    default:
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm sure there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Indeed. With LINQ. You can generate multiple instances with `Repeat` and join them with `string.Join`

```
var symbol = "\xE77B";
var separator = " ";
var count = 5
var result = string.Join(separator, Enumerable.Repeat(symbol, count));
```

This will work with `count = 0` too and generate an empty string.